# PHP For loop only execute one of five switch loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, switch-statement

I am pretty new to PHP and a little bit exhausted, so I would need some kick about my problem.

I write "for" sentence with "switch" function, but code only gives me back result in first loop (I have 5 loops) and then assign default value to variable. What am I doing wrong? A lot I guess.

```
$oblaki1 = $xml1->metData[10]->nn_shortText_domain_top;
  .
  .
  .

$show1 = "";
$show2 = "";
  .
  .
  .
$bar = array("$oblaki1","$oblaki2","$oblaki3","$oblaki4","$oblaki5","$oblaki6");

$show = array("$show1","$show2","$show3","$show4","$show5","$show6");

for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    switch ($bar[$i]){
        case "FG":
            show[$i] = "<img src='local/baz.png'height='70'width='70' /> ";
        break;

        case"DZ";
            $show[$i] = "<img src='local/bar.png' height='70' width='70' /> ";
        break;
           .
           .
           .
           .
    }
}
echo "$show[0]";
echo "$show[1]";
  .
  .
  .
```

Because same $bar[] could be emty, later I also have check with $foo[], which is always occupied:

```
$foo = array("$padavine1","$padavine","$padavine3","$padavine4","$padavine5","$padavine6");

for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    switch ($foo[$i]){
        case "XY":
            show[$i] = "<img src='local/XY.png'height='70'width='70' /> ";
        break;

        case"XX";
            $show[$i] = "<img src='local/XX.png' height='70' width='70' /> ";
        break;
          .
          .
          .
```

Comment: You don't really need to enclose a `php` variable with `"` if it is not in a string

Comment: _"for" sentence_ is called _"for" loop_ and there is no _switch function_ but _switch statement_

Comment: And what is the `.` columns for?

Comment: I think you can just create an empty `show` array, then push those `<img>` elements.

Comment: try to echo the $bar[$i] to debug and see why the swich don't 'get' the result you expect

Comment: @Swellar I think by dots they mean "some other code goes here (it's irrelevant for the question)"

Comment: @JakovL.. you are right YakovL  "some other code goes here (it's irrelevant for the question)".  Maybe the problem is, that i have later also same for loop with $bar1 arrey, but $show is the same and they fight with eachother?